# Ruby - Search hash keys with user-input + regex and return multiple matches

Tags: ruby, regex, hash

I used the Project Gutenberg #29765 English language dictionary file, re-formatted it, and created a few large hashes (A through D, etc) out of it.

I am using a lookup like this which is working fine and displays the definition when you type in a word-

```
$look = gets.chomp
$look = $look.upcase
puts " "
if (/^[A-D]/).match($look)
puts dicta[$look]
```

The problem is that some words have more than one entry- rather than extensively modify a 113,000 entry dictionary file, I thought I would just modify the duplicates from this-

```
dicta = { "BARE" => "def 1", "BARE" => "def 2"}
```

...to this

```
dicta = { "1| BARE" => "def 1", "2| BARE" => "def 2"}
```

I'd add a second lookup of some kind to find these duplicates

```
elsif (/^[0-9] + {user input}) ... (something?)
```

What do I need in order to make it find and display both duplicates for BARE?

I strongly suspect this is the complete wrong way to build all of this, but... any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: this `{"BARE" => ["def 1", "def 2"]}` seems to be a better data structure than what you have chosen, putting duplicates in a list still makes your hash lookup O1

Comment: Using globals (`$look`) is code smell. Don't use globals until you have a really good idea when and why you should use them. Instead learn how to use local and instance variables.

Comment: @bjhaid (hi bjhaid) has the right idea.  If your hash is `h` and "BARE" has just one definition, you could have either `h["BARE"] = ["def 1"]` or `h["BARE"] = "def "`.  In the latter case, you wouild need to check `if h["BARE"].is_a? Array..<multiple definitions> else...<single definition>...end`.  If you are not familiar with the term "code smell", you should know that if code smells, it nver never smells good.  You would not say, for example, "your code smells like freshly-baked bread".

Comment: Awesome! I did not know I could do that with a hash, but that did it! There were 14,000 entries which had duplicates- I was able to regex/excel juggle them into shape without too much fuss. Next I will go read about globals, locals and instance variables so I can reduce the smell. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @bjhaid Hi! Can one of you add that as an answer? Then I can check this off as answered... Thanks! –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this `{"BARE" => ["def 1", "def 2"]}` seems to be a better data structure than what you have chosen, putting duplicates in a list still makes your hash lookup O1 –  bjhaid

@bjhaid (hi bjhaid) has the right idea. If your hash is `h` and "BARE" has just one definition, you could have either `h["BARE"] = ["def 1"]` or `h["BARE"] = "def "`. In the latter case, you wouild need to check `if h["BARE"].is_a? Array..<multiple definitions> else...<single definition>...end`. –  Cary Swoveland